# WIA сканирование на C#, есть ли разница в коде, если сканер подключен к компьютеру через USB или если сканер подключен к компьютеру по локальной сети?

Tags: c#, wia

Есть необходимость сканировать документы в офисе через внутреннее приложение написанное на С#. Нашел отличную статью на хабре про wia сканирование. https://habr.com/ru/company/tinkoff/blog/310562/ . Взял это решение и немного доработал его под свои нужды. У самого стоит старенький сканер Epson Perfection V10 подключен он через USB. И у меня все работает, но в офисе сканеры подключены к локальной сети и видимо из-за этого (или нет) происходит ошибка HRESULT: 0x80210015 , а именно "Ваш сканер не обнаружен." Может ли это связано с тем что в офисе все сканеры подключены по локальной сети? Или все-таки проблема в том, что сканеры, которые стоят в офисе не поддерживают драйвер wia? Заранее благодарю.)

Comment: Скорее всего проблема не в том, что сканеры по сети подключены, а в том, что к ним нет доступа либо драйвер не установлен, то есть сканер не добавлен в список сканирующих устройств рабочей станции. Либо WIA библиотека, используемая в решении, устарела и не поддерживается современными сканерами. Возможно, были какие-то изменения со стороны Windows в этом плане. Вы смотрите материал 5-летней давности, он априори устаревший.

Comment: Т.е. лучше все таки использовать TWAIN?